# Find Child by Class and remove all the elements except the first one

Tags: jquery

I have a TR row id (myRow) and it has a child table and that table has rows with class ".CONTENTROW". I am using the following code to remove all the rows with class ".CONTENTROW" except the first one. This is the code I am using:

```
var myRow = $("#" + rowId).next().clone();
$(myRow).find(".CONTENTROW tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

The above does not seems to be working and does not remove any row. I tried using JSFiddle but JSFiddle is behaving in a strange way and not refreshing.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt6VQ/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$(myRow).find(".CONTENTROW").not(":first").remove();`

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle link but I cannot paste the whole thing since it is very very long. http://jsfiddle.net/Xt6VQ/1/

Comment: Seems like that the JSFiddle has some problems when updating the code. Your solution works perfectly and very neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

<s>If the row ID in `myRow` is not prefixed by a `#` you'll need to change the selector to:</s>

```
$('#' + myRow);
```

As your `myRow` variable is already  jQuery object (as you specified in the comments it's retrieved via `var myRow = $("#" + rowId).next().clone();`), you can get away with calling `myRow.find()` directly.

You also need to change your row selector to `tr.CONTENTROW:not(:first-child)`

What you have currently is matching all elements with a class of `CONTENTROW`, finding all of their combined descendants that are `tr`'s, and then selecting the first one matched.

For more info, see the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:gt`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector documentation.

So, to conclude;

```
myRow.find("tr.CONTENTROW:not(:first-child)").remove();
```

Comment: I get the myRow like this: var myRow = $("#" + rowId).next().clone();

Comment: Please check out the JSFIDDLE url in the original post.